# VBA: Primary key on ADODB.Recordset from query on Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, ado, adodb

I am working on a VBA routine that retrieves data from an Excel workbook, does some simple processing (turns string into upper case, removes spaces from the left and right ends, calculates codes, etc.) and creates a .csv file to be imported into the company's ERP via an embedded functionality. To do this I retrieve the data from the worksheet with an SQL-like query that opens an ADODB recordset, then I iterate through it modifying the field values and finally update the recordset, like this:

```
Private sub rsOps(ByRef cnn As ADODB.Connection, ByRef rs As ADODB.Recordset, ByRef wsOr As Worksheet)
Dim strSQL As String
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClientBatch
strSQL = "Select ROWID, {...some fields...}, ltrim(rtrim(Description)) as Descr, " _
        & "{...other fields...} " _
        & "From [" & wsOr.Name & "$]"
rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockBatchOptimistic
With rs
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then   'Check if there are any records
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
        While Not .EOF
            '{further data processing}
            .MoveNext
        Wend
        .UpdateBatch
    End If
End With
```

The problem is on ltrim(rtrim(Description)) and this makes the rs.UpdateBatch command to fail because it cannot retrieve the starting references anymore:

> Error -2147217864 (80040e38). Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been changed since it was last read.

Is it possible to enforce a primary key? My ROWID never changes so that could do the job, but I don't know how to set it.

**Edit**: The failure does not occur on either of these cases:

- Application of ltrim(rtrim(Descr)) while looping through the recordset rather than directly on the starting query
- The starting data does not contain any spaces at the start/end of the string (so it's unmodified by the query)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem however you could just run an update first.    `cnn.Execute "UPDATE [" & wsOr.Name & "$] SET Description = TRIM(Description)"`

Comment: Thank you. I actually managed to solve the problem by doing the trim while I am looping through the recordset, though your solution may be more efficient. I still don't understand why the other method would fail, since ROWID is unique for each record.

Comment: I think it may be that ado is looking for a declared primary key or a unique key on the underlying table. Is rowid defined (explicitly declared) to be a pk, or unique?

Comment: Not explicitly, in fact I was wondering how to do that...I mean, I can declare a primary key while creating a table on a SQL db, but how do you do that on an ADODB recordset whose data is the result of a query on an Excel worksheet? Maybe I am lacking some fundamentals on how ADO works on Excel worksheets, but I just can't figure that out.
Anyway, now the question is just about curiosity and learning, I managed to get around the problem and it's enough for my practical purpose...so I don't want to waste too much of your time 

Comment: Since the source is EXCEL ADO probably uses all columns as a 'key' to update. If you remove the ltrim(rtrim from the SQL (and fetch all the columns, in plain format), would it work (you can still perform that in VBA).